# Straight css inset shadow with border radius

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this:
[image: img1]

This is my result:
[image: img2]

My code:

```
box-shadow: -10px 0px 0px 0px #88c0dc inset;
```

I couldn't find anything online about this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `::before` pseudo-element to create your shadow:

```css
#shadow {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#shadow::before {
  content: "";
  box-shadow: inset 290px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 49px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px 1px 0px 5px;
  width: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow"></div>
```